# How to hide \n in terminal interface in bash?

Tags: linux, bash, printing, console, status

I would like to print on the console a status bar to show which file is being processed on a bigger script. I can do that with a little script that prints "COMPUTING SOLUTIONS" and at the end it prints "CALCULATIONS COMPLETED". I get this annoying problem when the script is completed where the text changes to 
"\nMPUTATING SOLUTIONS"

I tried to use echo which does the job fairly easy

```
echo -ne "COMPUTING SOLUTIONS...Template_${step_x}_${step_y}   \r"
echo '\n'
echo -ne 'CALCULATIONS COMPLETED - RESULTS IN SCRIPT DIRECTORY   \n'
```

At the end it should just print

```
COMPUTING SOLUTIONS...
CALCULATIONS COMPLETED
```

but instead it prints:

```
n\MPUTING SOLUTIONS 
CALCULATIONS COMPLETED
```

Comment: Please provide the script.

Comment: Maybe change `echo '\n'` to `echo ""`. Or maybe `echo -e '\n'`. Also see the [`echo(1)` man page](https://linux.die.net/man/1/echo).

Comment: Okay, this clears it up. I guess `echo -e '\n'` as @jww stated should help. Also why you keep the \r escape sequence in the first line? It will return the cursor to the first character. Then you see why your echo '\n' does not work, correct? :) Also given your code it will read `"\nMPUTING SOLUTIONS"` not `"n\MPUTING SOLUTIONS"`.

Comment: I tried to use echo -e '\n' instead and it worked!! :) Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

Easiest thing to do is simply not suppress printing of the newline if you intend to just add them back.

If you are going to print newlines explicitly, enable interpretation of backslash escapes like you did on the first and third lines, and print a newline \n rather than carriage return \r